# Apply CSS :not() and :hover in Less

Tags: css, less

I have some elements with a specific class (let's call `.option`), and some of them has an other class in addition (let's call `.selected`). I would like to apply some `:hover` style definition on `.option` elements, but only the ones that has no `.selected` class.

I already figured out that I have to use the `:not()` and `:hover` pseudo selectors, but none of their combinations resulted in something that I wanted.

And in addition I have to word this all in Less. I'm not very versed in Less and CSS.

```
<!-- I'd like to apply :hover only on those options that are not selected -->
<div class="option">
   option 1
</div>
<div class="option selected">
   option 2
</div> 
<div class="option">
   option 3
</div>
<div class="option">
   option 4
</div>
```

Okay in the mean time I figured out that `.option:not(.selected):hover` is the CSS selector that I need...I just don't know how to write it in Less.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I found it. If anyone is has the same issue, you can achieve this in less like this:

```
.option{

    /* ... */

    &:not(.selected):hover {

        /* ... */

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help you with the LESS:

```
.option {
    &:not(.selected) {
        &:hover {
            color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```